# Как перевести координаты нажатия по кнопке в тип double? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Как перевести координаты нажатия по кнопке в тип double? Получаю координаты

```
@IBAction func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tapLocation = sender.location(in: sender.view)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tapLocation` это `CGPoint`, который содержит значения типа `CGFloat`, если нужен `Double`, сделайте так

```
let x = Double(tapLocation.x)
let y = Double(tapLocation.y)
```